# Letter Game Challenge Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

A word game awards points for the letters used in a word.  The lower the frequency of the letter in the English language, the higher the score for the letter.  Write a program that asks the user to input a word.  The program should then output the score for the word according to the following rules:

[image: Table for letters and score in numbers]

How would you add a score together for letters that the user has inputted?

I am having issues with this

```
#Letter Game Challenge
letters = ("e","a","r","i","o","t","n","s","l","c","u","d","p","m","h"
           ,"g","b","f","y","w","k","v","x","z","j","q")

points = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
          ,24,25,26)

def main():
    global word_input
    print ("Input a word to see the score")
    word_input = input()
    if any(letter in word_input for letter in letters):
        l1()
    else:
        print ("Enter a word with letters in!")
        main()
```

This is what I have so far just don't know how to split the word inputted and check for a letter and give a score for it.

Comment: please show us that you have something own written already. We can then see what the problem is and nudge you to right direction.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: More to the point: work through the problem with pencil and paper, the way *you* would do it as a human being.  Write down the steps you used.  Now do your best to write that in code.  Add just a few statements at a time: get each small addition working before you add the next.

Comment: As it is, your current code doesn't execute.  The logic doesn't seem to follow a clear path toward a solution.  Your commentary boils down to "I don't know the language techniques needed to design my program."  That suggests that you need more time with language references (your class notes, on-line documentation, etc.) rather than posting in Stack Overflow.

Comment: As a side-note: the line `main()` is over-indented.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through the letters of a word use a for loop:

```
for letter in word_input:
```

You will need to look up the score for each letter. Try using a dictionary:

```
scores = {"e": 1,
          "a": 2, 
          #etc
```

Then you can look the score of a letter with `scores[letter]`